# Unable to see the custom action added in ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-server, ribbon, custom-action

I designed a custom action and added it to the ribbon. After successfully deploying it, its feature is activated, but I still cannot see the custom action in the ribbon.

This works perfectly fine on the development machine but when deployed on the production, it is neither giving error nor showing the newly added button.

I do not know what is the issue.

Comment: Do you have any web parts on the page?

Comment: Yes, all of them are working well

Comment: If you have listview webpart then try changing the "Toolbar type" to "Full toolbar"

Comment: Check the ULS logs after feature activation you may see something there. Is the ribbon targeted to a specific list or view type?